# savetxt save only last loop data

Tags: python, numpy

Can someone please explain?

```
import numpy

a = ([1,2,3,45])
b = ([6,7,8,9,10])
numpy.savetxt('test.txt',(a,b))
```

This script can save well the data. But when I am running it through a loop it can print all but cannot not save all. why?

```
import numpy

a = ([1,2,3,4,5])
b = ([6,7,8,9,10])
for i,j in zip(a,b):
    print i,j
    numpy.savetxt('test.txt',(i,j))
```

Comment: You aren't actually using numpy arrays. Maybe the brackets were meant to be preceded by `numpy.array`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You overwrite the previous data each time you call `numpy.savetext()`.

A solution, using a temporary buffer array :

```
import numpy

a = ([1,2,3,4,5])
b = ([6,7,8,9,10])

out = []

for i,j in zip(a,b):
   print i,j
   out.append( (i,j) )

numpy.savetxt('test.txt',out)
```

Answer (score 2):

`numpy.savetxt` will overwrite the previously written file, so you only get the result of the last iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The faster way will be to use open with

```
import numpy

a = ([1,2,3,4,5])
b = ([6,7,8,9,10])

with open('test.txt','wb') as ftext:  #Wb if you want to create a new one,
    for i,j in zip(a,b):              #ab if you want to appen it. Her it's wb
        print i,j
        numpy.savetxt(ftext,(i,j))
```

It will be really faster with a large array

Answer (score 0):

You should `append` (i,j) rather than overwriting previous ones

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b = np.array([6,7,8,9,10])

np.savetxt('test.txt', np.column_stack((a, b)))
```